# Is there a largest prime p such that J_0(p) completely splits into elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, jacobians

The question in the title is related to a more general question. Namely does there exist an integer $N$ such that for all curves $C/\mathbb C$ of genus $> N$ one has that not all simple isogeny factors of $J(C)$ are elliptic curves.

Now since over $\mathbb Q$ the isogeny factors of $J_0(p)$ correspond to galois orbits of newforms it seems to me that the question wether there is a largest prime $p$ such that $J_0(p)$ splits completely into elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$ should be easier and I wonder wether the answer is already known.

I suspect that the answer is yes and that $p = 37$ is the largest prime such that $J_0(p)$ completely splits into elliptic curves. Indeed using Cremona's database of elliptic curves I verified that 37 is the biggest prime below 300000 such that $J_0(p)$ completely splits into elliptic curves.

The reason I only ask it for prime levels $p$ is that I already showed that if $p = 37$ is indeed the largest prime such that $J_0(p)$ completely splits into elliptic curves, then $N = 1200$ is the largest composite number such that $J_0(N)$ completely splits into elliptic curves.

Comment: Your "more general question" (first sentence) is strange. $JC$ is a simple abelian variety for a general curve $C/\Bbb{C}$ of genus $g$,  for every $g$.

Comment: I don't see why your comment makes my first question strange. It asks wether something is true for all curves of a certain genus not just the generic one, so the answer might be different. It is certainly not true that the jacobian is simple of all curves of genus $g$ if  $g > 1$.

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't realize that you are allowing the simple factor to be $J(C)$ itself.

Comment: Ok, I modified my question so that people in the future will not get confused in a similar way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer, due to Jean-Pierre Serre, can be found in an [unpublished note](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~cohen/serretrace.dvi) of Henri Cohen where he characterizes the odd integers $N$ such that $J_0(N)$ is isogenous to a product of elliptic curves.

For your question, $N$ is prime, and only $p=11$, $13$, $17$, $19$ et $37$ satisfy this condition. (For $p=13$, $J_0(p)$ has dimension $0$.)

In the general case, Cohen gives the following Theorem:

**Theorem**. *The only odd values of $N$ for which $J_0(N)$ is isogenous to a product of elliptic curves are $N\leq 21$, as well as $ N = 25$, $27$, $33$, $37$, $45$, $49$, $57$, $75$, $99$ and $121$. (When $N\leq 9$, $N=13$ and $N=25$, $J_0(N)$ is zero.)*

Comment: Cool, I deduced Cohen his generalisation from Serre his result in a different way. Namely just find for each prime $p_i \leq 37$ the largest $e_i$ such that $X_0(p_i^{e_i})$ is isogenenous to a product of elliptic curves. Then any $N$ such that $J_0(N)$ splits into elliptic curves has to divide $\prod_{p\leq 37} p_i^{e_i}$ leaving a finite number of cases to check. I did this finite computation and the splitting $N$ can be found [on my website](http://www.mderickx.nl/misc/splitting_N).

Answer (score 9):

In fact we know the list of *all* $N$, whether even or odd, for which
$J_0(N)$ is isogenous to a product of elliptic curves.  See

> Takuya Yamauchi, On $\mathbb Q$-simple factors of Jacobian varieties of modular curves, *Yokohama Math. J.* **53** (2007), no. 2, 149-160.

An alternative proof (which also corrects a minor error in Yamauchi's list) is given in section 5 of the recent paper

> Noam D. Elkies, Everett W. Howe, and Christophe Ritzenthaler: Genus bounds for curves with fixed Frobenius eigenvalues, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **142** (2014), 71-84.  arXiv: [1006.0822](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0822).

See page 82 of 
[the online version](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2014-142-01/S0002-9939-2013-11839-3/home.html)
or page 12 of the arXiv preprint.